# Recordset getString returns a value but also throws invalid column name exception under SQL Server

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-server-2012, recordset, getstring

I am querying an existing table that I cannot alter using JDBC.  My SQL Server query of "SELECT * FROM " returns and I log the results with

```
logger.debug("Retrieved record firstname=" + rs.getString("FirstName"));
```

The logs shows  the data returned but ALSO that an exception was thrown as that indicates the column name is invalid.

```
10:54:54.546 [main] DEBUG com.goprecise.ams.model.GetUserTest - Retrieved record firstname=System Account
10:54:54.754 [main] ERROR com.goprecise.ams.model.GetUserTest - The column name FirstName is not valid.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name [FirstName] is not valid.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:699)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2525)
    at com.goprecise.ams.model.GetUserTest.testJbpmOrganizationTableViaJdbc(GetUserTest.java:95)
```

The column is in the table and the correct value is displayed for the field in the record, so why is an exception about it being an invalid column name thrown?  How can this be corrected? "FirstName" is the name of a column defined as a varchar and not null; isn't a String is returned for a varchar using JDBC?
The code surrounding the exception (raised on the line shown above) is:

```
    String sqlSelectUser = "SELECT TOP (5) * FROM " + helper.getUserDbTable();          
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(helper.getJdbcUrl(), helper.getDbUsername(), helper.getDbPassword());             
        logger.info(sqlSelectUser);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlSelectUser);
        rs.next();
        logger.debug("Retrieved record firstname=" + rs.getString("FirstName"));
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
```

Comment: FYI, this is a client-side error, not one that's returned by SQL Server.

Comment: You don't show the line of code where the exception is raised.  Also, the error message rather intriguingly appears twice, slightly differently, in your log messages, once with square brackets and once without.  Are you perhaps writing `rs.getString("[FirstName]")` somewhere in your code?

Comment: The exception is in the logging statement.  Adding code in an edit.

Comment: Looking at your code, (a) you are not checking the return value of `rs.next()`, so your code won't handle the case that your query returns no rows, and (b) the table name in your SQL string may vary between two successive calls to this code, so there's no guarantee that you are always calling it with a tables that has a column `FirstName`.  Also, your log output appears to be missing the `info` line logging the SQL string `sqlSelectUser` in your code.  Your log output shows a `DEBUG` and an `ERROR` line, so `INFO` lines should also be included.

Comment: This particular table has existed for many years and has thousands of rows, so I know it will have records - hence no checking of the recordset.  I could test it instead of displaying the value - since my goal of the JUnit is to confirm that the database can be accessed - solving my problem but not answering why the error is raised